# How might I script-call SIGINT (CTRL+C)?

Tags: bash, signals, pid, sigint

my issue is this: how can I implement the call to SIGINT (CTRL+C) by means of code, rather than have a user key-in the signal?

The script is light-hearted fun, but also a learning tool (for me), as I am progressively implementing features and functionality in a bid to increase my understanding an knowledge of BASH scripting.

Specifically, I am finding it difficult to utilise signal trapping and how to make it work with the rest of my script. Essentially, after a period of time, SIGINT should be called and there should be a fall-through to the next set of instructions before reaching the end of the program. While there are many examples of capturing SIGINT, dealing with Process IDs in the foreground and background, I cannot make sense of them, where, I could fairly confidently attempt implementation.

What I have is this,

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

read -p "What is your name?" name
read -p "How old are you?" age

printf "Hello ${name^}; you are ${age} years old."
printf "Let's find out when you will become rich."

trap ctrl_c INT

ctrl_c()
{
  flag=1
}

dots()
{
  if [[ "$" -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "."
  fi
  if [[ "$2" -eq 2 ]]; then
    echo ".."
  fi
  if [[ "$3" -eq 3 ]]; then
    echo "..."
  fi

flag=0
dot_count=1

while [[ "$flag" -eq 0 ]]; do
  if [[ $dot_count -eq 4 ]]; then
    dot_count=1
  fi
  
  printf "\r%sCalculating%s" "$(tput el)" "$(dots "$dot_count")"
  dot_count=$((dot_count + 1))
  sleep 1
done

  printf "\r%sCalculating... [Done]" "$(tput el)"

    ...

get_rich=$((($RANDOM) + $age))

printf "You'll be rich by the time you are $get_rich!\n"
```

The function `ctrl_c()` seems to serve no purpose, because, to my knowledge, it is not called; only setting `flag=0` causes the Progress Bar to function. Physically entering `CTRL+C` stops the Progress Bar and allows the program to continue to its end. So, is `ctrl_c` actually necessary? Could the while-loop be written another way without `flag=0`?

Ultimately, is there a way to programatically send SIGINT?

Comment: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html

Comment: `kill -INT $$` sends SIGINT to the pid of your script (`$$`).

Comment: @Shawn: Thank you for the suggestion. As you may have appreciated at some point, the manpages can seem impenetrable and is certainly abstruse. It presents a lot of information, but how exactly to apply the knowledge - that takes a better man than myself.

Comment: @dan: Thank you for the suggestion. I have written the same snippet, but have attempted to put it in a countdown timer constructed with a while-loop; I still have to key-in ```ctrl+c```. So, my issue now, is of placement; where do I put the code to gain the functionality I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are right that in this case you can get rid of `ctrl_c`.
2. You can simply add `kill -INT $$` command as @dan suggested somewhere in the `while` loop. In the example below I added it to when `dot_count` equals 4. In that case there is no need for pressing `Ctrl+C` on your keyboard; after `dot_count` reaches `4` the script will terminate.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

read -p "What is your name?" name
read -p "How old are you?" age

printf "Hello ${name^}; you are ${age} years old."
printf "Let's find out when you will become rich."

trap flag=1 INT

dots()
{
  if [[ "$1" -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "."
  fi
  if [[ "$2" -eq 2 ]]; then
    echo ".."
  fi
  if [[ "$3" -eq 3 ]]; then
    echo "..."
  fi
}

flag=0
dot_count=1

while [[ "$flag" -eq 0 ]]; do
  if [[ $dot_count -eq 4 ]]; then
    dot_count=1
    kill -INT $$
  fi
  
  printf "\r%sCalculating%s" "$(tput el)" "$(dots "$dot_count")"
  dot_count=$((dot_count + 1))
  sleep 1
done

printf "\r%sCalculating... [Done]" "$(tput el)"


get_rich=$((($RANDOM) + $age))

printf "You'll be rich by the time you are $get_rich!\n"
```

I get the following running it on an Ubuntu 22.04:

```
gomfy:signal$ bash script.sh 
What is your name?G 
How old are you?98
Calculating... [Done]You'll be rich by the time you are 26348!
```